# ACE Editor & custom wrap mode

Tags: javascript, word-wrap, ace-editor

We use ace-editor in our project with antlr4 and our language and one moment we must implement soft word wrap on key press Shift+Enter. Does any opportunity exist to do that easy? May be does ace-editor has an option for wrap?

Comment: ace has an option for wrapping `editor.setOption("wrap", true)`, But are you sure you need soft wrap, that is wrap without changing the text, usually key press is used for hard wrap.

Comment: It's my mistake, thank you. Of course "hard wrap"